# Rewrite URL removing all after domain name

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i need rewrite all URL of specific domain to other exact URL without parameters, all URL `old.domain.com/*` to `new.domain.com`
I have set this rule into .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.domain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.domain.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.domain.it [R=permanent,L]
```

so, if i go to

`old.domain.com/foo` or

`old.domain.com/foo/bar` or

`old.domain.com/foo/bar/index.php`

it work perfectly, but if i go to `old.domain.com/index.php?goofy`, it redirect to `new.domain.com/?goofy`, i can redirect always to `new.domain.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the url is `old.domain.com/index.php?goofy` Mod-rewrite appends `?goofy` to its destination url. This is because  mod-rewrite appends `query string` (Url part after  the `?` character) to the redirected url .

If you are on Apache 2.4 you can use `QSD` Query string Discard flag to remove old query string from new url.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.domain.it [R=permanent,L,QSD]
```

If your apache version is below 2.4  ,simply add an empty question mark `?` at the end of the target url to remove old query string.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://new.domain.it/? [R=permanent,L]
```